# OpenCV cv::imwrite causes memory leak

Tags: c++, opencv, memory-leaks, queue, mutex

I'm writing some OpenCV code to write any `cv::Mat`(s) in a queue to a file. Unfortunately, the calls to `cv::imread` seem to be causing a memory leak. When those lines are commented out, no memory leak occurs.

```
void ck::file_pipe_handler() {
    std::vector<int> compression_params;
    compression_params.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
    compression_params.push_back(0);
    while (true) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> pop_lock(
            file_pipe_mutex, std::defer_lock);
        if (file_pipe.empty()) {
            usleep(10);
            continue;
        }
        pop_lock.lock();
        frame_details frame_deets = file_pipe.front();
        file_pipe.pop();
        pop_lock.unlock();

        auto base_dir = output_file_name + "/" + frame_deets.serial_number;
        auto rgb_reg_dir = base_dir + "/rgb_registered/";
        auto rgb_raw_dir = base_dir + "/rgb_raw/";
        auto depth_dir = base_dir + "/depth/";

        // If you comment out the imwrite calls here,
        // the memory leak does not occur
        if (register_rgb)
            cv::imwrite(rgb_reg_dir + std::to_string(frame_deets.timestamp_rgb)
                        + ".png", frame_deets.frame_registered.first);
        cv::imwrite(rgb_raw_dir + std::to_string(frame_deets.timestamp_rgb)
                    + ".png", frame_deets.raw_rgb);
        cv::imwrite(depth_dir + std::to_string(frame_deets.timestamp_depth)
                    + ".png", frame_deets.frame_registered.second, compression_params);

        frame_deets.raw_rgb.release();
        frame_deets.frame_registered.first.release();
        frame_deets.frame_registered.second.release();
    }
}
```

I added the release calls to the end just to make sure that the `cv::Mat`(s) are correctly freed. Also I'm certain that the queue isn't filling up. I'm using OpenCV 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concurrency issues -- just move the unlock after the cv::imwrite calls.